# Adding Lottie dependency in build.gradle.kts gives an error 'Unresolved reference: airbnb'

Tags: android, lottie

I'm trying to add Lottie library into my project but can't handle with adding lottie dependency.

I'm using Android Studio 2023.2.1 Beta 2, and it appears that it uses brackets instead of quotation marks (idk, i'm kinda new to android studio). So I tried to add this line `implementation(com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.3.0)`
And had this in return `Unresolved reference: airbnb`
Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your entire build.gradle files (project level and app level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the library as a string:

```
implementation("com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.3.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified direct answer:

`implementation(libs.lottie)`